# How to find client ID and secret for R's Google Analytics package

Tags: r, google-analytics, credentials

I have been given access to a Google Analytics account and would like to use its data through R. In the demo [here](https://github.com/Tatvic/RGoogleAnalytics/blob/master/demo/data_extraction_demo.R), you can see the line `token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)`. How would I go about finding these values? I'm pretty new to both R and Google Analytics so it's possible that this is very simple, but I've been Googling for a while now and haven't been able to find an answer for my scenario (they all seem to involve creating a new project rather than using it for an existing one).

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps for getting both the client ID and secret outlined in the RGoogleAnalytics R package notes:

> - Go to https://console.developers.google.com
> - Create a New Project and enable the Google Analytics API
> - On the Credentials screen, create a new Client ID for Application Type > "Installed Application".
> - Copy the Client ID and Client Secret to your R Script as shown in the Examples section below

That may be a little confusing for a first time user (like me), so I'll just outline what I did.

1) Go to https://console.developers.google.com

2) In the dashboard tab on the left, hit "Enable API"

3) Look for the section titled "other APIs" and click "Analytics API"

4) This will guide you to create a new project for your R application Auth. You will need to be signed into your Google account that is tied to Google analytics.

5) Enable the API by clicking Enable API in blue next to the Analytics API name in the Dashboard tab.

6) Once your Google Analytics API is enabled, click "create credentials" labeled in blue.

7) In the drop down, click "OAuth client ID"

8) For application type, choose "other" and name your client whatever you want.

9) Then your client ID and secret should pop up. Copy these into your R code `token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)` but make sure to have the client ID and secret in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple it is [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). Create a project in the [Google developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). The [Hello Analytics Java](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java) example is comparable.